# Laravel artisan cron task not working on ubuntu 18.10

Tags: laravel, ubuntu, cron

Hello I have enabling the cron feature for Laravel on Ubuntu 18.10 on Vultr VPS server.

I have added the cron task to the cron jobs list using the command

```
crontab -e
```

Then I have added the command listed in the laravel documentation

```
* * * * *       cd /var/www/html/hva && php artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1
```

I have made sure that cron is running and I can see that the task is running if I run

```
sudo grep -i cron /var/log/syslog|tail -3
```

Which returns

```
May 20 20:56:01 HiRe-Pro-Web CRON[1819]: (root) CMD (cd /var/www/html/hva && php artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1)
May 20 20:57:01 HiRe-Pro-Web CRON[1862]: (root) CMD (cd /var/www/html/hva && php artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1)
May 20 20:58:01 HiRe-Pro-Web CRON[1898]: (root) CMD (cd /var/www/html/hva && php artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1)
```

Does anyone have any suggestions where I'm going wrong here.

Comment: what happens if you run the command  directly? `php artisan schedule:run`

Comment: it works fine then just not at the cron task

Comment: Is there a only one version of php running on the server? you can locate where the PHP executable is, and try somethig like this  `* * * * *  /opt/php71/bin/php /var/www/html/hva/artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1`

Comment: there is 2 php file inside /usr/bin one is php and one is php7.2

Comment: So, edit the cron and try with absolute path `* * * * * /usr/bin/php /var/www/html/hva/artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1` or `* * * * * /usr/bin/php7.2 /var/www/html/hva/artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1`. I don't  know which you are using in your project

Comment: Both tested but same result.